# PostgreSQL query with SUM takes long to execute

Tags: postgresql

I have table 'logs' with approximately 25 million rows (and growing daily) and my queries are taking almost 10 seconds to execute.

I am using Debian Linux and PostgreSQL 9.1.

```
-- Table: logs

CREATE TABLE logs
(
  ad_id character(24),
  id serial NOT NULL,
  created_at timestamp without time zone,
  campaign_id character(24),
  zone character(50),
  request_url character(500),
  click smallint DEFAULT 0,
  impression smallint DEFAULT 0,
  view smallint DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT logs_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE INDEX index_ad_id
  ON logs
  USING btree
  (ad_id COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

CREATE INDEX index_campaign_id
  ON logs
  USING btree
  (campaign_id COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

As you can see I have created indexes on ad_id and campaign_id and there is no obvious speed difference when executing query noted below.

```
select sum(click) as click, sum(impression) as impression
from logs
where campaign_id='561b9a248280de632f207e5d'
  and created_at > '2015-10-01 00:00';
```

Are there any techniques when dealing with this kind of queries on this kind of amount of data.

At this time I am caching results in Memcached to speed serving data, but because this data now needs to be displayed in realtime at current state responsiveness of application is bad.

I was initially using InfluxDB but performance was horrible compared to PostgreSQL.

I went through guidelines for speeding up PostgreSQL server but there were no positive changes.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
explain select sum(click) as click, sum(impression) as impression from logs where ad_id='5602609e8280de4d9a1d8bb8' and created_at > '2015-10-01 00:00';
                                       QUERY PLAN                                       
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=697098.52..697098.53 rows=1 width=4)
   ->  Index Scan using index_ad_id on logs  (cost=0.56..695875.68 rows=244568 width=4)
         Index Cond: (ad_id = '5602609e8280de4d9a1d8bb8'::bpchar)
         Filter: (created_at > '2015-10-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
(4 rows)

Time: 0.645 ms
```

Comment: how about an index on `created_at`?

Comment: Please post an `EXPLAIN` output so that we can all see what plan is being executed.

Comment: I added index on created_at and there are some performance improvements. Now query takes about 6 seconds.

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.5's BRIN indexes could be useful for this kind of query.

Comment: `EXPLAIN (BUFFERS, ANALYZE)` would be more useful than plain `EXPLAIN` really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A composite index on `(campaign_id, created_at)` instead of separate indexes may be useful.

You should probably use the `"C"` collation for the column for faster comparisons, since you don't need localized collations.

Also, at the cost of some insert performance, you might try creating an index that covers all the relevant columns to allow an index-only scan.

Here's what I'd do:

```
CREATE INDEX whatever ON logs (
    campaign_id COLLATE "C",
    created_at,
    click,
    impression
);
```

then query with:

```
....
campaign_id = '561b9a248280de632f207e5d' COLLATE "C"
....
```

If you get syntax errors about `COLLATE "C"` then your PostgreSQL is too old and you don't get to use that feature.